# Python/Pandas - directory of data frames calling specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to call a specific column within a dataframe from a list of dataframes created from a directory of csv files

I have a directory of dataframes created from multiple csv files:

```
df_dict = {x: pd.read_csv('{}'.format(x)) for x in files}
```

where files is my directory for each csv.

This code works well and leads to my desired output (below).

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import time
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
import glob
import os

#File counter
path, dirs, filess = next(os.walk('C:/Users/eagles/Desktop/Financials'))
file_count = len(filess)

#File location & dataframe creation
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/eagles/Desktop/Financials/*.csv')
df_dict = {x: pd.read_csv('{}'.format(x)) for x in files}

#Print each dataframe from directory
for x in range(file_count):
   print(df_dict[files[x]])

{'C:/Users/eagles/Desktop/Financials\\DELL.csv':           Date Symbols  Adj Close    ...           Low       Open    Volume
0   2019-08-20    DELL  48.470001    ...     48.189999  48.720001   1842700
1   2019-08-21    DELL  48.980000    ...     48.549999  48.669998   1389500
2   2019-08-22    DELL  49.040001    ...     48.419998  49.430000   1619800
3   2019-08-23    DELL  45.810001    ...     45.730000  47.750000   3670700
4   2019-08-26    DELL  46.410000    ...     45.950001  46.000000   2040900
..         ...     ...        ...    ...           ...        ...       ...
83  2019-12-17    DELL  49.930000    ...     49.560001  49.720001   2366600
84  2019-12-18    DELL  50.000000    ...     49.619999  50.000000   2302800
85  2019-12-19    DELL  49.889999    ...     49.779999  50.060001   1518000
86  2019-12-20    DELL  49.619999    ...     49.509998  50.299999   2704500
[87 rows x 8 columns], 'C:/Users/eagles/Desktop/Financials\\EBS.csv':           Date Symbols  Adj Close   ...           Low       Open   Volume
0   2019-08-20     EBS  42.900002   ...     42.880001  44.020000   312300
1   2019-08-21     EBS  42.099998   ...     41.400002  43.509998   372000
2   2019-08-22     EBS  41.599998   ...     41.310001  42.380001   365900
3   2019-08-23     EBS  40.820000   ...     40.590000  41.680000   347800
..         ...     ...        ...   ...           ...        ...      ...
83  2019-12-17     EBS  52.680000   ...     51.169998  51.610001   265800
84  2019-12-18     EBS  52.340000   ...     51.320000  52.540001   374300
85  2019-12-19     EBS  53.919998   ...     51.689999  52.430000   250600
86  2019-12-20     EBS  54.419998   ...     53.590000  53.900002   817200
[87 rows x 8 columns], 'C:/Users/eagles/Desktop/Financials\\GRPN.csv':           Date Symbols  Adj Close  Close  High   Low  Open    Volume
0   2019-08-20    GRPN       2.51   2.51  2.54  2.41  2.43   7692500
1   2019-08-21    GRPN       2.51   2.51  2.54  2.48  2.54   5141800
2   2019-08-22    GRPN       2.47   2.47  2.67  2.46  2.49   9225700
3   2019-08-23    GRPN       2.40   2.40  2.47  2.37  2.45   8404700
..         ...     ...        ...    ...   ...   ...   ...       ...
83  2019-12-17    GRPN       2.39   2.39  2.57  2.35  2.54  18253900
84  2019-12-18    GRPN       2.39   2.39  2.44  2.38  2.42   4645600
85  2019-12-19    GRPN       2.28   2.28  2.40  2.24  2.39  11894500
86  2019-12-20    GRPN       2.23   2.23  2.29  2.21  2.28  11354400
```

I can also call a specific dataframe with `df_dict[files[0]]`

But what I cannot do is call a specific dataframe and a specific column.

The output I'd like to see is would only include the 'Close' column for each dataframe:

```
#Dell
df_dict[i]['Close']
      Date          Close
    0   2019-08-20  48.470001 
    1   2019-08-21  48.980000 
    2   2019-08-22  49.040001
    3   2019-08-23  45.810001 
    4   2019-08-26  46.410000
#EBS
df_dict[i+1]['Close']
     Date          Close
    0   2019-08-20 48.470001 
    1   2019-08-21 48.980000 
    2   2019-08-22 49.040001
    3   2019-08-23 45.810001 
    4   2019-08-26 46.410000
#GRPN
df_dict[i+2]['Close']
      Date          Close
    0   2019-08-20  48.470001 
    1   2019-08-21  48.980000 
    2   2019-08-22  49.040001
    3   2019-08-23  45.810001 
    4   2019-08-26  46.410000
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: maybe something similar to: `pd.concat([df[["Date", "Symbol", "Close"]] for df in df_dict])`?

Comment: could be a solution.

Would it ultimately work wherein i could call each dataframe individually?

i.e., I would need to be able to call 'DELL''CLOSE', 'EBS''Close', & 'GRPN''CLOSE' seperatley

Thanks!

Comment: it this case, you could merge all dataframes into one and filter accordingly. e.g. `main_df = pd.concat([df for df in df_dict]); dell = main_df.loc[main_df["Symbols"].eq("DELL")][["Date", "Close"]]`
 or `main_df.loc[main_df["Symbols"].isin(["DELL", "EBS", "GRPN"])]` to select all three of them etc

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dictionary of data frames?

Comment: Sure. my dictionary comes from this code: df_dict = {x: pd.read_csv('{}'.format(x)) for x in files} as above. the output is each file in the dictionary as a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Didn't able to simulate similar data. But u may try following code

`for x in range(file_count):
    print(df_dict[files[x]][['Date','Close']])`